# Transforming from matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to transform this expression from matlab to python:

```matlab
g(:,m)=sum ((z,2).)⁄((N.*y.^alpha));
```

I did it as bellow:

```py
g[:, m] = np.divide(np.sum(z,1), np.multiply(N, y**alpha))
```

However, the following error appears:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (25,25) into shape (25)
```

The vector `z` is originally `(25,100)`, `N=100`, `y0 =(25, 1)`, `alpha=-1`

I believe that, when adding the columns in `z`, it should generate a vector `(25,1)`.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Don't stop with "it should generate ..."  We expect you to do a little work to trace your code.  Deconstruct your complex expression and *know* what type and shape each subexpression has.  That will likely show your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`np.sum(z, 1)` is actually giving you a vector with shape `(25,)`

To keep it in `(25, 1)` shape you need to do `np.sum(z, 1, keepdims=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to transpose(or reshape):
np.sum(z,1).reshape(25,1)

It seems your result shape is (25,25). The error you got as you assign it into the column m which is just one dimensional so it the dimensions mismatch.

Comment: Following your recommendations, the following error appears: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (25,1) into shape (25)